# Codenameone display property os

Tags: codenameone

When doing:
Display.getInstance().getProperty("OS")
what are the valid return values?

The documentation shows:
OS - returns what is the underlying platform e.g. - iOS, Android, RIM, SE...

I'm pretty sure it returns "JS" for the Javascript version, but I'd like to know what is returned for Mac desktop and Windows desktop.

Comment: Did you try using Windows and Mac?

Answer (score 1):

It's a mistake to use that API which is why it's not heavily documented. If you need native functionality you would use native code anyway which is where you can write OS specific code without resulting to code that looks like `if(os_a) do_this(); if(of_b) do that();`.

If you insist on doing that despite our strong opinions against it then a better API is [this](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/ui/Display.html#getPlatformName--). The platform names are mentioned in the e.g. section.

Comment: We supply a desktop version of our app for users that don't want to have to switch between their computer & mobile device. There are some features that are only available on the desktop version like attaching files. The code I inherited tested for "JS" because that was how we delivered the desktop version. However, we are having so many problems with it where it freezes after sitting idle, or requires emptying the cache to log in, that we're trying the actual desktop builds instead. I need to test for desktop versions. The API you gave only lists mobile. Is there a way to test for desktop?

Comment: It's mac and win but it might conflict with the windows port too. A better approach would be to use `Display.getInstance().isDesktop()`.